# VMware or Virtual PC 2007

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines

I am wondering which should I use. I want to setup a virtual machine that has Team Foundation Server on it. It will also have windows Server 2008 and Microsoft SQL 2008 installed.

Which of these two are easier to setup? Which is easier to configure networking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this for production, business use or just for personal testing and messing around?

TFS2010 is a bit of a beast, especially when running SQL on the same box, and you'll need an additional VM runnign concurrently if you're planning to use the *build server* feature (it should not be run on the TFS server itself).

If you have a piece of hardware that you can dedicate to the task, look at running ESXi, Microsoft Hyper-V server, or XenServer, then running the VMs on top of that. They're all free, and installation is straight forwards as long as the hardware is compatible.

If you absolutely have to run on top of an existing Windows installation, then VMWare Workstation or Virtual PC will probably suffice. Outside of this, there's a good feature comparison matrix [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_platform_virtual_machines).

Comment: sort of all 3. It is to test a project that I am working on for production, It is for a my business and it is personal testing and messing around(I never used team foundation server and am trying it out)

Answer (score 0):

For me there was no difference in ease of setting up or getting an internet connection.

VMware Server allows 64-bit guest machines.  The host CPU must support 64 bits but the host OS doesn't have to.